# How to figure out the meaning behind Recv-Q and Send-Q from netstat?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, netstat

```
netstat -ntp

Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name     
tcp   8216172      0 127.0.0.1:9503         127.0.0.1:47654         ESTABLISHED 34390/python 
tcp        0 4189632 127.0.0.1:47686        127.0.0.1:9503          ESTABLISHED 34379/python  
tcp   8203139      0 127.0.0.1:9503        127.0.0.1:47666         ESTABLISHED 34390/python 
tcp   8179744      0 127.0.0.1:9503        127.0.0.1:47686         ESTABLISHED 34390/python
```

I have read the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36466744/use-of-recv-q-and-send-q) but still have some doubts about if the program is having queues stacked on send or receive queues. For eg. what is happening in below two lines of netstat -ntp output ? is the processId 34390 is getting queued data while sending or receiving and on which port number the queue is occuring on ?

```
tcp 8216172  0 127.0.0.1:9503 127.0.0.1:47654 ESTABLISHED 34390/python
tcp   0 4189632 127.0.0.1:47686   127.0.0.1:9503  ESTABLISHED 34379/python
```

Answer (score 12):

```
tcp 8216172  0 127.0.0.1:9503 127.0.0.1:47654 ESTABLISHED 34390/python
```

means that process 34390 has a connection open, between port 9503 on the local host, and port 47654 on the local host, and that 8216172 bytes of data have been received by the kernel on port 9503 but haven’t yet been copied by the process.

```
tcp   0 4189632 127.0.0.1:47686   127.0.0.1:9503  ESTABLISHED 34379/python
```

means that process 34379 has a connection open, between port 47686 on the local host, and port 9503 on the local host, and that 4189632 bytes of data have been sent from port 47686 but not acknowledged yet (so they’re still in the TCP window).

Comment: is TCP window the correct terminology here?  I would think it's that the bytes are in the kernel's TCP socket send queue for this service.